# php, ajax and json encoding/decoding

Tags: php, json, jquery

I'm using jQuery and [jquery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) to post data to a PHP script.

```
       $.post('<?php echo url_for('/ajax.php'); ?>', 'data=' + $.toJSON(order), function (response) {

                if (response == "success") {
                    $("#respond").html('<div class="success">Item Saved!</div>').hide().fadeIn(1000);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#respond').fadeOut(1000);
                    }, 2000);
                }
         })
```

If I console.log(order) I get the following JOSN:

```
{"details":[{"template_id":"25","font_size":"22"}]}
```

In my ajax.php file I have:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST["data"]);
var_dump($data);exit;
```

Which returns 'NULL'

But when I have the following code:

```
$data = $_POST["data"];
var_dump($data);exit;
```

It returns:

```
string(61) "{\"details\":[{\"template_id\":\"25\",\"font_size\":\"26\"}]}"
```

Is there any reason why it is escaped?

What is the easiest way to decode this?

Thanks

Comment: i think variable "order" is already a json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may need to disable `magic_quotes_gpc` in your php.ini or .htaccess file which is adding the slashes to your post variables.

Or you could just call `stripslashes` on $_POST['data'] like so:

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["data"]));
```

Comment: The function is called `stripcslashes` instead of `stripslahses`

Comment: `stripslashes` would do the job, but disabling `magic_quotes_gpc` is always the better solution if you are able to do it.

Comment: @P1nGu1n no, `stripcslashes` serves another purpose, to remove magic quotes, `stripslashes` is the right function.

Comment: Yeah it was a typo... I have disabled magic quotes and all seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dataType: 'json' to your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $.toJSON(order),
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {

      if (data.response) {
        $("#respond").html('<div class="success">Item Saved </div>').hide().fadeIn(1000);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('#respond').fadeOut(1000);
                    }, 2000);

      }

    }

});
```